# Threads callback

Tags: c++, multithreading, callback

I have this code, possibly wrong written:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void callback()
{
    cout << "Callback called" << endl;
}

void task(void(*clb)())
{
    /* code...  */
    clb();         // (1)
}

int main()
{
    thread th1(task, callback);
    thread th2(callback);
    th1.join();
    th2.join();
}
```

1) What is the connection or motivation between terms callback and thread ?

2) line marked (1) is this only a function call using function pointer (callback) or do I call a thread ?

3) When should I use a callback from inside a thread and when just a function call ?

Comment: One question per question please. As-is this is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The meaning of callback varies between people and languages. Some people call a callback any function pointer, others say that a callback is a function/ function pointer or function object passed as a function argument. I agree with the second one. In this case the void callback() function decays to a function pointer. Whether a functor/function object is also a callback, I don't know. It's definitely callable.

2) clb(); in task() function is just calling the callback function. At this point the thread is already running.

3) Whether to call a function pointer or function is up to you. Function pointers have advantages in that they can be assigned to other functions at runtime, but they're dynamically dispatched. In other words the function call isn't compiled as machine code, it's called through a pointer meaning the program needs to look up its address and run it. This is slower. Function pointers and functors/function objects/lambdas allow a lot of flexibility, but if you don't need it then don't use them.

The line:

```
thread th1(task, callback);
```

Is creating a new thread. The first constructor argument is the function that the thread will run. Because the task() function takes a callback or function pointer, the second argument in thread() is the function, given as a pointer. Inside the task() function the callback is called with

```
clb();
```

Which calls the function void callback();

```
thread th2(callback);
```

Creates a new thread and executes callback function.

```
th1.join();
```

Blocks the current thread, your main() thread from continuing until the thread th1 is finished.

```
th2.join();
```

Blocks the main thread until th2 thread is finished.

By thread finishing I mean when the function given to the thread constructor finishes/returns.